# I cannot use history.push() properly with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner with ReactJS and I'm trying to redirect the page using the `history.push()` but without success. Can anyone help me saying what's wrong with my code? I know it's possible to use the React Router but it won't help for what I'm trying to do.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.history.push('/redirected');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Redirect!!!
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

After clicking on the button I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

On the line:

```
this.props.history.push('/redirected');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, are you using react-router? Because it's possible to do what you are trying to do with react-router. history is an object which comes when you pass the router props to your component. if you are using react-router post the router configuration.

Comment: I'm not. I think the React Router won't help me as I need to redirect outside the component. So I think the best solution is to use the history.push() (I may be wrong)

Comment: history.push is a function that comes along with react-router. You cannot use it without it.

Comment: If I import the react-router it should work? I don't know how I could fix it

Comment: You need to set up react-router, you can look for online tutorials for that. And if the redirection is to an external link, you can view my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

Install history:

```
npm install --save history
```

Initialise browser history in index.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
```

Use:

```
browserHistory.push('/pathToRedirect')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the redirect is to an external link:

```
window.location.href = 'your-url';
```

Although I have to warn you if the redirection is to an external link, react-router won't work either the way you want it to.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but this makes the page reload as well. I'd like to change de URL without "refreshing" the page.

Comment: For that, you'll need react-router. I suggest you study up about it, will help you in the long run. It's almost impossible to build nice applications without it and it's not complex.

Comment: Although I have to warn you if the redirection is to an **external link**, react-router won't work either the way you want it to. @AlexandrePaiva

Comment: I appreciate all your help and suggestions, Rohit. I'm still learning ReactJS. The Jackkobec's solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's work for me.

```js
props.history.push('/signup', {...props})
```